# Apache httpd bad request when accessing by ip address - Review Board

Tags: apache, ip-address, bad-request, review-board

I have setup Review Board and it works fine when accessed from localhost.
When I try to access it by ip (from LAN), I get BAD REQUEST.

I have copied apache-wsgi.conf to my apache conf directory.

apache-wsgi.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8088>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/reviews.als.kz/htdocs"

    # Error handlers
    ErrorDocument 500 /errordocs/500.html

    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIScriptAlias "/reviews" "/var/www/reviews.als.kz/htdocs/reviewboard.wsgi/reviews"

    <Directory "/var/www/reviews.als.kz/htdocs">
            AllowOverride All
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Prevent the server from processing or allowing the rendering of
    # certain file types.
    <Location "/reviews/media/uploaded">
            SetHandler None
            Options None

            AddType text/plain .html .htm .shtml .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phps .asp
            AddType text/plain .pl .py .fcgi .cgi .phtml .phtm .pht .jsp .sh .rb

            <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                    php_flag engine off
            </IfModule>
    </Location>

    # Alias static media requests to filesystem
    Alias /reviews/media "/var/www/reviews.als.kz/htdocs/media"
    Alias /reviews/static "/var/www/reviews.als.kz/htdocs/static"
    Alias /reviews/errordocs "/var/www/reviews.als.kz/htdocs/errordocs"
    Alias /reviews/favicon.ico "/var/www/reviews.als.kz/htdocs/static/rb/images/favicon.png"
```

I have installed reviewboard into /var/www/reviews.als.kz directory.
Chown-ed it to apache:apache.

I run it on Fedora 21.
Review Board version 2.0.12
Apache httpd version 2.4.10

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

The problem had been with python settings.
Added my ip address to ALLOWED_HOSTS within settings_local.py file and everything worked.

Thanks

Comment: It works. In CentOS, the file path is /var/www/codereview/conf/settings_local.py

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When you configure your reviewboard, you have to give it a site name . Some thing like "reviewboard.mycompany.com". It doesn't have to be a registered name just make up something.
Then when you try to access the reviewboard main page, use the site name (reviewboard.mycompany.com) as the URL. You'll of course need to add the made-up hostname to to your /etc/hosts so your machine can resolve the address.

Create a host entry / DNS entry with the site name. like

reivews.mycompany.com x.x.x.x

It's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Fixed it by adding this line to my httpd.conf :

> HttpProtocolOptions unsafe